Is sound louder in a solid compared to air?
Consider this experiment, where it is shown that the sound of the metronome is louder when you hold the acoustic sensor directly towards the table. Many explanations in the internet argue that it is because sound travels faster in solids than in air. But from my point of view, this has nothing to do with the volume. So is there a clear explanation why it is the case (with reference to research papers or basic principles?)

Loudness is proportional to the energy density of the acoustic wave. You are correct in thinking that the speed of propagation in a medium is not really the culprit here, but rather the attenuation of the acoustic wave as it travels through both mediums. Both measurements are done at approximately the same distance away from the source of the sound- the metronome- but sound waves more readily dissipate into random thermal motion in gases then they do in liquids and solids. This is one of the reasons why whales can hear each other over much vaster distances in the ocean than terrestrial creatures can hear each other through air- sound waves lose energy far less spatially rapidly as they propagate in liquids and solids.

Interesting hypothesis, but unfortunately wrong in this case. Over that small a distance the attenuation in air is completely negligible. At room temp and humidity it's about 5 dB per km at 1 kHz.


Consider this experiment, where it is shown that the sound of the metronome is louder when you hold the acoustic sensor directly towards the table.

That's not exactly what the experiment shows: it shows that the sound pressure meter displays a higher number when the microphone is in contact with the table, rather than in free air.
The meter measures the electrical signal output by its microphone, which comes from the displacement of the microphone's membrane relative to its body. In a known medium like air, it is possible to know with good accuracy the relationship between pressure waves amplitude (loudness) and membrane displacement, so the SPL meter can be calibrated.
However , what it measures is still relative displacement of the membrane relative to the body.
When the metronome clicks, it transmits vibration into the table, which propagates inside the wood.
When the sound pressure meter's microphone tip touches the table, it will pick up these vibrations and vibrate along with the table.
Thus the SPL meter is not used the way it is supposed to be, which is with the body immobile and only the microphone membrane vibrating along with incoming sound waves. In this experiment, the body is vibrating, and the membrane will also pick up sound from the table via the air, although the amplitude and relative phase are unknown.
Contact between solid surfaces is much more effective at transmitting vibration than going from solid, through air, then another solid. Thus we can guess that the microphone body may vibrate a lot more relative to the membrane when in contact with the table, than the membrane relative to the body does when in contact with the air. The display simply reflects this.
To validate this hypothesis, one could touch the table with various parts of the SPL meter, for example the other end opposite the microphone. This should get a completely different reading, because sound transmission through the SPL meter's plastic body will be different than through the metal tip, but that's not an issue as the goal of this experiment would be to demonstrate that vibrations of the SPL meter's body are part of the measurement.
In fact the SPL meter is acting a bit like a stethoscope. I'm saying "a bit" because in the case of the stethoscope the sensitive membrane is designed in such a way to contact the surface while the body does not... but both devices do pick up surface vibrations.

This is quite complicated and a whole lot of things are happening here. You need to track the sound from source to receiver and analyze each individual step for each version.
The source
Like a clockwork a metronome as an "escapement" which allows a spikey wheel  to advance one spike at a time for each swing pendulum. The actual "click" is generated when the wheel spike hits the escapement on the pendulum axis. A metronome clicks exactly the the same way a mechanical  clock does.
That vibration is then mechanically transmitted into the housing of the metronome. The wall panels vibrate and that transmits sound into air. These panels are specifically designed to do this well and the internal resonances inside the Metronome do help here too.
At the same time, the vibration travels through the feet of the metronome and couples into the table. This coupling depends a lot the material and mechanical design of the feet. Hard rubber or plastic feet couple a lot a lot better than soft felt feet. To simplify things: the mass of the metronome and the spring of a feet form a mass-spring lowpass filter and the the the softer the feet, the lower the cutoff frequency and the less vibration will be transmitted.
The path
The air path consists of two major components: the direct sound from the metronome and the reflected sound from the walls and surfaces around you. The latter is a function of the size, shape and surface materials. A tiled bathroom is a lot louder than a well padded living room. The distance at which reflected and direct energy are the same is called "critical distance" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_distance) and is on the order of 0.5m in typical residential environments.
The table path is primarily a modal one. The vibrations are reflected at the table edges and form complicated standing wave patterns which are often referred to as modes. At each point on the table you get a different mix of the modes so the spectrum of the vibration depends a lot on the exact pick up location.
Both the mode energy in the table and the reflected sound energy in the room represent an equilibrium between energy going in and attenuation. The main loss mechanisms here is NOT the attenuation of the medium itself but "lossy reflections".
The receiver
The SPL meter has an internal microphone (typically an Electret microphone). This has a very small membrane in front of a static metal plate. Vibration of the membrane changes the electric capacity of the contraption. The membrane is designed to react well to airborne sounds. In good SPL meters, it's also mechanically well isolated to minimize the impact of handling noise. In shitty SPL meters, it's just bolted on or glued together. The quality of the mounting impacts very much how sensitive the device is to mechanical vibration.
Finally: the experiment itself
In the first case, we measure the air borne sound only. The absolute number will depend A LOT on the distance to metronome and the room acoustics. Technically there is a secondary structure born path through table, floor, shoes, human body into the SPL meter but since there is a lot of severe impedance mismatches along the way the contribution can be neglected.
In the second case we measure both: air borne sound AND the path through the table directly into the SPL meter. Since the air borne component is still there we would always expect the second measurement to be equal or larger than the first one. By how much depends on A LOT of factors, the major ones being

Feet material of the metronome
Vibration isolation (or lack thereof) of the microphone in the SPL meter
Properties of the contact between SPL meter and table surface: materials, pressure, size and shape of contact area, etc.

